# How to check existence of multiple tables using a single query

Tags: sql-server

Currently I am using:

```
select * 
from sys.tables 
where name = 'table name'
```

But it is taking long time since there are many tables and I have to check each one of them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using IN like

```
select * from sys.tables where name IN ('tablename1','tablename2',...)
```

or you can instead try

```
SELECT  1 
FROM    systable INNER JOIN sysuserperm ON systable.creator = sysuserperm.user_id
WHERE   sysuserperm.user_name = 'yourusername' AND 
        systable.table_type = 'BASE' AND 
        systable.table_name IN ('tablename1', 'tablename2')
GROUP   BY sysuserperm.user_name, systable.table_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Once can use this:

```
USE DbName
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
      AND TABLE_NAME IN ('tb01','tbl02',...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of table names to check, put it into a table variable and use a code similar to the one below:

```
declare @t table (
    SchemaName sysname not null,
    ObjectName sysname not null,
    primary key (ObjectName, SchemaName)
);

-- Populate this with your data
insert into @t (SchemaName, ObjectName)
values
    (N'dbo', N'SomeTable1'),
    (N'dbo', N'AnotherTable2'),
    (N'abc', N'DEF');

if exists (
    select 0 from @t t
        left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES xt on xt.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.SchemaName
            and xt.TABLE_NAME = t.ObjectName
    where xt.TABLE_NAME is null
    )
    select concat(t.SchemaName, N'.', t.ObjectName) as [MissingObject]
    from @t t
        left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES xt on xt.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.SchemaName
            and xt.TABLE_NAME = t.ObjectName
    where xt.TABLE_NAME is null;
```

The aforementioned approach can be easily expanded for multiple kinds of objects. You can replace `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` with `sys.all_objects` and modify the schema name comparison accordingly.